# Stripe with React JS

Tags: reactjs, npm, stripe-payments, child-process

I need to create token with Stripe.js in React JS, but I can't find any easy way. In node.js I would do something like this:

```
   stripeClient.tokens.create({
      card: {
        number: '4242424242424242',
        exp_month: 12,
        exp_year: 2050,
        cvc: '123'
      }
```

But the Stripe npm module doesn't work for me in React JS. I'm getting error:

> Cannot resolve module 'child_process'

So since this is node pibrary obviously, I would like to use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

But I'm not sure what should be the best practice to implement external libraries in React

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just go ahead and add it like any other client side library, like you might have done in the past.

Include this script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

Then use the global that it exposes inside your code.

```
import React from 'react';

// we didn't have to import stripe, because it's already
// in our global namespace.
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh');
```

It's not as clean as being able to require it from NPM, but it will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you totally worked, just my linter is not happy about that.

Comment: You should be able to provide your linter with a list of globals to ignore. For example, with ESlint: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for guidance when using Stripe in React: [Accept Stripe Payments with React and Express](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/) is an article with a straight forward implementation of Stripe in React (create-react-app) and a minimal Express server that handles your payment requests and forwards them to the Stripe platform. The article keeps the boilerplate to a minimum and comes with an open source project that you can simply try out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

**Switch to BrainTree**
They support a client-side NPM package which can be used with *[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)* ([Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) / [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)): https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/javascript/v3#npm

`npm install --save braintree-web`

**Unfortunately Stripe and React don't fit well together**
The version of [Stripe on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe) is for server-side use only; so even if you Webpack / Browserify the library (as provided by *create-react-app*), then client-side features for configuring the public-key and tokenizing the credit-card information are missing.
For the client-side, Stripe prefers ["stripe.js"](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) to be used from an external URL: `https://js.stripe.com/v3/`. Unfortunately, external URLs aren't well-suited for *create-react-app* - for example, ES6 `import` can't be used, and the external file is not bundled by Webpack. Furthermore, version (v3) forces users to use an `elements` method and query the DOM (basically going against React).

Answer (score 0):

You can add direct link in html file but the other side of this, It will load every time even if their is no requirement.
So i would suggest you to add stripe library via your code to stay with **lazy** lodaing concept.

```
            const script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = "https://js.stripe.com/v3/";
            script.async = true;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Then

```
Stripe = Stripe('your keys').
```

After this `Stripe.createToken('add any of your card element').then(setOutcome)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this apporach...
In public index.html

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
```

and in the component

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(window.Stripe.setPublishableKey){
        window.Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_LkK8cMTD4YXUImjZquRnAqXb');
    }
}
```

Its working for me...

Then in calling Stripe methods you just need to do:

```
!window.Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(
```