# using external library into typescript and webpack project

Tags: typescript, webpack

I've been really very stuck for some **weeks** trying to solve that, I'm really suach a exhausted man...

Up to now, and according to [this guide](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-jQuery):

```
npm install stripe --save
npm install @types/stripe --save-dev
```

and I've added this in to `webpack.common.js`:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Stripe: 'stripe'
})
```

Then, into my typescript component I've added this:

```
import * as Stripe from '@types/stripe';
```

Nevertheless I'm getting this error:

> [ts] File '.../node_modules/@types/stripe/index.d.ts' is not a module.

I've also tried:

```
import stripePackage from 'stripe';
```

But I'm getting the same message:

```
[ts] File '.../node_modules/@types/stripe/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

**EXTENSION**

By now, I've uninstalled `@types/stripe` and I've added the script cdn reference on `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

By other side, I've also added the reference into my typescript:

```
import * as Stripe from 'stripe';
```

1. I'm using VSCode in order to develop my typescript project. It's magic for me `VSCode` is available to give methods on `Stripe` object.

   - How does VSCode know where `stripe` is located? (Remember I've only added a `<script type=...>` tag into `index.html`. It's something magic for me.
   - How does `webpack or typescript` create the link between `<script>` tag reference into my typescript code? I'm not able to figure out how it's provided...

Comment: and if you only do `import 'stripe'`

Comment: Compiler tells me nothing now. But, how should I use defined types into `'stripe'`?

Comment: I've just realized, I'm able to use `Stripe` straightforwardly. Which are the issues I'm not able to use `import * as Stripe from '@types/stripe'` or `import * as Stripe from 'stripe'`...?

Comment: `@types` are just type definitions. This is not a library you can import. It depends on how the package is written, but if you just have a script tag in your index.html, and the `@types` installed, there is no need for an import in typescript anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the GitHub issue [Feature requests: Typescript definitions #296](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/296) the type definitions of `@types/stripe` are outdated. The [stripe/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/stripe/index.d.ts#L1) says they are for Stripe 2.x, but the current version of [Stripe on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe) is `4.15.1`.

For now you'll have to live without type definitions, uninstall `@types/stripe` with:

```
npm uninstall @types/stripe --save-dev
```

You always have to import the module itself, not the type definitions. So it is:

```
import * as Strip from 'stripe';
```

Also the `webpack.ProvidePlugin` is only used for legacy modules that depend on a module being available globally and webpack will simply add the import to each module that tries to use that global. See [Shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#provideplugin). If you're just using it in your own code, you can leave off the `ProvidePlugin`.

*Note: Stripe on npm is for server side bindings only, you can't bundle them into an app for a browser*.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I've added some related issues has came up trying to handle it with your approach on post. Could you give me some lights please? _(I'm using stripe in browser)_

Comment: I don't really know anything about stripe. But you can you include the stripe script in a `<script>` tag in your HTML and use the global `Stripe`. You might be interested in looking at a similar question [Stripe with React JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527455/stripe-with-react-js).